# How to refresh Fragment When move to page

Tags: android, fragment

I have FragmentA ,FragmentB ,FragmentC in ViewPager

When app runs the first time I state on FragmentA

FragmentB create and call method onResume() automatic

When I move to FragmentB I want to call method onResume() again

for start some animation again.

How do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement a [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) (or a [`ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)) and attach it to the ViewPager. Depending on the effect you want, you can use either of the following two options:

1. `onPageSelected(int position)` (in combination with `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`) - Called when the scroll state changes.
2. `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)` - This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.

You can then (re)start the animation when those methods get called.